# Combining latest with previous value in an observable stream

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I'm trying to figure out how to take an observable sequence of `T` and get both the most recent and previous values of `T` in my subscriber. Here is my spike code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var latest = new Subject<string>();
    var previous = latest.SkipLast(1);
    var latestWithPrevious = latest.CombineLatest(previous, (l, p) => new { Latest = l, Previous = p });

    latestWithPrevious.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Latest: {0} Previous: {1}", x.Latest, x.Previous));

    latest.OnNext("1");
    latest.OnNext("2");
    latest.OnNext("3");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I am wanting the following output:

```
Publishing 1
Publishing 2
Latest: 2 Previous: 1
Publishing 3
Latest: 3 Previous: 2
```

However, I am getting the following:

```
Publishing 1
Publishing 2
Latest: 2 Previous: 1
Publishing 3
Latest: 3 Previous: 1
Latest: 3 Previous: 2
```

So the publication of "3" to `latest` is triggering two ticks in `latestWithPrevious`: the first has an old value for `Previous`, and the second has the correct value for `Previous`.

How can I achieve my goal here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Skip(1)`, not `SkipLast(1)`.  `SkipLast` skips the last N entries in the stream.

Also, `CombineLatest` will still trigger for each side when it changes so you will get more events than you want.  Use `Zip` instead of `CombineLatest`.  `Zip` only triggers after each side produces its next value.

Finally, reverse the semantics.  `latest` is the series skipping the first value, `previous` is the series including the first value.

```
var source = new Subject<string>();
var previous = source;
var latest = source.Skip(1);
var latestWithPrevious = latest.Zip(previous, (l, p) => new { Latest = l, Previous = p});
```

Comment: this is nice, thanks, but i wish there was a way to get a emission on the very first change of the source. the way you have it with the zip there must be a change from both. i wish i can get (latest = "mystring", previous = null) for example.

Comment: @j2emanue change the two assignments to this: `previous = source.StartWith(null); latest = source;`

Comment: that does not seem to work. that will emit null BEFORE emitting the very first time.  instead i used a BehaviorSubject and called subject.onNext("") before anyone even subscribes just to init it.  i wish there was a better way to init.  thanks though